# Marshmallow runtime permissions for cordova plugins

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Recently i have found that [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) has been updated to support the marshmallow runtime permissions. i want to know if this solves all the permissions issues or its better to make changes in our plugin to make it compatible with android>=6.0

Comment: Not sure what you mean by all the permission issues. But almost all the plugins have resolved all their permission issues related to marshmallow as far as i know. To name a few - Cordova file plugin, camera plugin To answer your question, as per the official documentation, looks like it takes care of all permission issues

Comment: i use cordova-plugin-barcodescanner and it fails on marshmallow. I have gone through the native implementation and there is no code for handling runtime permission to use camera.

Comment: Did you had a look at these plugins - https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner https://github.com/greenaddress/WalletCordova/tree/master/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner